# Managed package apex from trigger

Tags: managed-package

I have a managed package apex classes.
Can i execute them from my apex triggers?

Managed package apex creates records, so i want to execute it from a trigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot access Apex code that's in a managed package, unless it is made global by the publisher of the package.

Comment: If the class is made global, can i access it through apex anonymous window and execute it

Comment: Both the class and the method should be global. If this is your own managed package, beware that restrictions apply once global classes are packaged.